# If indolent means causing little or no pain, is there a word that means causing a lot of pain or passing out/death

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm sure about the "causing a lot of pain" part but I don't know about what followed.

Is there a word that means "causing a lot of pain or passing out"  or "causing a lot of pain or death"?

> His condition went from healthy to indolent and then indolent to _______?

Comment: The only meaning of *indolent* I've ever encountered is *lazy, slothful*. I can sorta-kinda see the progression of meaning from "indolent teenager" to "indolent tumor (meaning slow-growing)" to "indolent tumor (meaning causing little pain because it's slow-growing)", but I wouldn't suggest using *indolent* with this meaning unless you're writing in a medical journal.

Comment: @Marthaª: actually, the progression seems to have been in the opposite direction.

Comment: Well, the "in" here is the negative prefix, so it would be logical for the opposite to be "dolent." I don't think that's used much, though I did find a paper that describes a "dolent tumor": http://www.bloodjournal.org/content/bloodjournal/82/10/2967.full.pdf?origin=publication_detail&sso-checked=true

Comment: By the way, it doesn't seem to me that "indolent" is typically used in the way you use it in your example sentence, to refer to a person's condition. Most commonly, this adjective seems to be applied to objects or parts of the body, such as "indolent tumors." In that context, the opposite would be something like "painful" in normal language. I don't know if there's a technical term.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**terminal** (if the prognosis is death)

> 2. (of a disease) predicted to lead to death, especially slowly; incurable.
>      *"terminal cancer"* –[Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=terminal%20definition&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8)

His condition went from healthy to indolent and then indolent to *terminal*.

---

**excruciating** (if the problem is pain)

> intensely painful. –[Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=excruciating%20definition&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8)

His condition went from healthy to indolent and then indolent to *excruciating*.

---

The guy who passed out, **fainted**.

> The autonomic nervous system regulates your heart rate and blood pressure. When you experience sudden pain, your heart rate and blood pressure can rapidly decrease, which affects the amount of blood flowing to your brain. This stress on the body, primarily the sudden loss of blood, can result in fainting. –[Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=fainting%20from%20pain&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8)

Also, [you cannot die from pain](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/9668/can-one-die-from-pain).

Comment: Since Google results can change, it might be better to link to Google's sources. The source of the first definition seems to be [Oxford Dictionaries](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/english/terminal) (unclear which specific dictionary) and the source of the description of fainting is a "[Go Ask Alice](http://goaskalice.columbia.edu/answered-questions/fainting-and-low-pain-tolerance)" post.

Comment: Google, simply, is not a reference. Link to what sites you found on Google, please.

Comment: @NVZ: The tricky part is that Google itself doesn't seem to list its source for definitions. There may be some description of it somewhere, but this Wikipedia article seems to suggest that they haven't make the source public: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Dictionary

Comment: The *Go Ask* link looks like plagiarism from WebMD anyway. Google lists no source for the definitions. I perused no web sites, I only used a browser. My source was Google.

Comment: @Mazura: I understand, and it makes sense to attribute it to Google, but as I said earlier, the problem is that Google is not a very stable reference. They seem to have switched dictionaries in 2010; they might do so again within a relatively short time period. I found a meta post that recommends not using Google as a source: [Is Google Dictionary a valid definition reference (in particular in answers)?](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/7052/is-google-dictionary-a-valid-definition-reference-in-particular-in-answers)

Comment: @sumelic [Permissions:](https://www.google.com/permissions/geoguidelines/attr-guide.html) "You can find the attribution in the line(s) shown on the bottom of the Content in the products along with copyright notices, such as “Map data ©2015 Google”. " There is no © at the bottom of Google's definitions. No further action is required. This may be bad form, but IMO it most certainly should *not* be against 'the rules'.

Comment: "**nobody** has the right to say what is an approved source, whether for a community-moderated site or for English as a whole." [What to reference when answering a question?](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/2267/what-to-reference-when-answering-a-question)

Comment: I look up definitions all the time and quoting Google is easy. But I take the time to visit dictionaries online to use as a reference to my answers.

Comment: @sumelic Any dictionary is "not a stable reference" in that their link structure can change and the information presented at a particular page can change. That's why our policy is to avoid link-only answers, but this isn't a link-only answer. It includes the definition here so that future readers don't need to go any further than this page in order to get their answer.

Comment: @Mr.ShinyandNew安宇: Hmm... you're right. Links are never "stable" anyway. I guess rather than the link, the part that I was talking about as being "stable" was the actual name of the dictionary, which will not change even if the dictionary updates its definitions.

Answer (score 1):

Consider **on the verge of death** (or "at the death'door").

> Definition: very near the end of one's life. (Often an exaggeration.)
>
> Examples:
>
> - *I was so ill that I was at death's door for three days*.
> - *The family dog was at death's door for three days, and then it finally died*.

```
 Edit following @NVZ comment:
```

For a single word, **ailing** may perhaps fit.

Comment: I would've answered similarly but OP has used only the SWR tag so far.

Answer (score 0):

As hinted at by @sumelic, in a comment above, the use of **[indolent](http://medical-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/indolent)** as you have defined it (and as it seems to be defined in a number of dictionaries) is unusual outside of the medical sense. Consider:

> *indolent* adjective Medspeak Referring to **a condition that may linger
>   longer, but often slowly progresses to a more advanced stage**—e.g.,
>   indolent lymphoma, indolent malignancy, indolent myeloma.
>
> Vox populi Slow growing.
>
> Segen's Medical Dictionary. © 2012 Farlex, Inc. All rights reserved.

and

> **in·do·lent** (in'dō-lent), **Inactive; sluggish; painless or nearly so,
>   said of a morbid process**. [L. in- neg. + doleo, pr. p. dolens (-ent-), to feel pain] Farlex Partner Medical Dictionary © Farlex 2012

and further

> Lymphomas are commonly also categorized as **indolent** or **aggressive**.
>   Indolent lymphomas are slowly progressive and responsive to therapy
>   but are not curable with standard approaches. Aggressive lymphomas are
>   rapidly progressive but responsive to therapy and often curable.

From a search for [indolent](http://www.merckmanuals.com/professional/hematology-and-oncology/lymphomas/non-hodgkin-lymphomas) in the Merck manual.

These are examples of the use of indolent as a fairly narrowly defined adjectival descriptor of a growth, tumour or other malignancy.

Your question might be best answered by **aggressive** being the opposite of indolent in a medical sense.  Whether this necessarily means painful is moot.

Physicians often use [exquisite](http://medical-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/exquisite) pain to describe intense pain. This may answer part of the pain question.